# Android: is it possible to remove a system-managed notification programmatically?

Tags: android, android-notifications

I've made an application that configure a vpn profile and connects to it. When I'm connected, I want just my notification to be shown, but android provides its own notification that is shown during the lifetime of a VPN connection.

Is there anyway to "delete" that notification, or, at least, to delete the corresponding icon from the top of the screen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not possible on Android, sorry.

You cannot control notifications outside of your own app, regardless of whether they belong to another third party app or the system. Only your own notifications may be updated or dismissed by you.

Comment: So, I can imagine that I also cannot modify the message?

Comment: I've seen that sometimes the notification does not appear.
I can imagine that the android system stores a sort of "flag" to remember that the user has accepted to use the VPN.
Do you know where this part of the code could be found within the Android kernel?

Comment: So how Pushbullet let me dismiss notification from other apps?