# Programmatically disabling/enabling notifications

Tags: android

Is there a way I can programmatically disable notifications of individual programs? I'd like to build a list of all programs installed on my device then check the ones I don't want to receive notifications from and hit one button to disable/enable them.

I'm trying to build an app that will allow me to enable some/all notifications with a button click and re-enable them via either a button click or after a predetermined period of time. Does Android support that? NotificationManager doesn't seem to have those properties.

Comment: you can see following answer may be help full to you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9367196/detect-a-new-android-notification/9632076#9632076

Answer (score 8):

It is not possible to disable notifications from other apps. you can only control notifications generated by your own app.

[Turn off notifications of an app programatically on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15819249/turn-off-notifications-of-an-app-programatically-on-android)

[Android: is it possible to remove a system-managed notification programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16019868/android-is-it-possible-to-remove-a-system-managed-notification-programmatically)

Answer (score 1):

**You can do it with shared preferences.**

You can set notification settings in Shared Preferences and later if you receive any message then you can decide to show Notification or not.

*Below Snippet is for ReactNative but you can use same for Native Apps as well*

```
  /**
     * Toggle Notification Setting
     *
     * @param showNotifcation
     */
    @ReactMethod
    public void toggleNotification(boolean showNotifcation) {

        if (showNotifcation) {
            Toast.makeText(reactAppContext, "Notification Enabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(reactAppContext, "Notification Disabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        getPrefernceHelperInstace().setBoolean(reactAppContext, ENABLE_NOTIFICATION, showNotifcation);
    }
```

Later in Message service class

```
public class ReactFireBaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    private NotificationUtils notificationUtils;

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

        //Check if Notn are Enabled?
        if (getPrefernceHelperInstace().getBoolean(getApplicationContext(),
                ENABLE_NOTIFICATION, true)) {

          //Show Notification
        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "ReactFireBaseMessagingService: Notifications Are Disabled by User");

        }
    }
```

See Code SNippet

https://github.com/hiteshsahu/react-native-fcm-android/blob/master/android/app/src/main/java/com/hitesh_sahu/fcm/service/ReactFireBaseMessagingService.java

[image]

Comment: Mathew Pierce asked something else. He wanted to create some app that can handle global notification manager.

Comment: It does not work for notifications when the application is closed.

Answer (score 0):

no you cant, maybe on rooted device, but it's another story...

Answer (score 0):

I can't remember what it was like in 2013 but I just use the settings app on the device. This has worked for at least 5 years on every Android device I've ever used.

It should be possible to build a MDM app that does the same. Something like "Test DPC".