# How can I turn ON/OFF "Show notification" programmatically in android

Tags: android, notifications

I have a requirement what I need to enable/disable the "Show notification" programmatically of App Info. I googled it for so much time but couldn't get proper solution. Is this possible in android to turn ON/OFF "Show notification" programmatically?. Thanks in advance.
[image]

Comment: do you mean enable/disable notifications only from your app or from the whole device?

Comment: yes @OShiffer your right.

Comment: @VinodPattanshetti but what do you want? Only your apps notification or from the whole device?

Comment: only app notifications @BrunoBieri. Like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17667406/programmatically-disabling-enabling-notifications.

Comment: @VinodPattanshetti have you followed the answers of this question? This one can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9632076/1306012

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9367196/detect-a-new-android-notification/9632076#9632076 This is different what I expected.

Comment: what service you are using to show notifications? alarm manager?

Comment: @PavelPoley see my requirement is to just How to TURN ON / OFF the show notification programmatically that's all, Nothing else I want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, there is not way to turn on/off programatically notifications, the only way we can do this using following code.

```
public class CustomToast {

  private static final String CHECK_OP_NO_THROW = "checkOpNoThrow";
  private static final String OP_POST_NOTIFICATION = "OP_POST_NOTIFICATION";

  public static void makeText(Context mContext, String message, int time) {
    if (isNotificationEnabled(mContext)) {
      //Show Toast message 
      Toast.makeText(mContext, message, time).show();
    } else {
      // Or show own custom alert dialog
      showCustomAlertDialog(mContext, message);
    }
  }

  private static boolean isNotificationEnabled(Context mContext) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
      AppOpsManager mAppOps = (AppOpsManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.APP_OPS_SERVICE);
      ApplicationInfo appInfo = mContext.getApplicationInfo();
      String pkg = mContext.getApplicationContext().getPackageName();
      int uid = appInfo.uid;
      Class appOpsClass;
      try {
        appOpsClass = Class.forName(AppOpsManager.class.getName());
        Method checkOpNoThrowMethod =
            appOpsClass.getMethod(CHECK_OP_NO_THROW, Integer.TYPE, Integer.TYPE, String.class);

        Field opPostNotificationValue = appOpsClass.getDeclaredField(OP_POST_NOTIFICATION);
        int value = (int) opPostNotificationValue.get(Integer.class);
        return ((int) checkOpNoThrowMethod.invoke(mAppOps, value, uid,
            pkg) == AppOpsManager.MODE_ALLOWED);
      } catch (ClassNotFoundException | NoSuchMethodException | NoSuchFieldException
          | InvocationTargetException | IllegalAccessException ex) {
        Utils.logExceptionCrashLytics(ex);
      }
      return false;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }

  private static void showCustomAlertDialog(Context mContext, String message) {
      if (!(mContext instanceof Activity && ((Activity)mContext).isFinishing())) {
          AlertDialog.Builder mBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
          mBuilder.setMessage(message);
          mBuilder.setPositiveButton(mContext.getString(R.string.ok),
                  new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                      @Override
                      public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                          dialog.dismiss();
                      }
                  });
          mBuilder.setCancelable(true);
          AlertDialog alertDialog = mBuilder.create();
          alertDialog.show();
      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You would have to keep a Boolean flag and add a check before posting a notification from your app. Save that Boolean flag in SharedPreferences. Once the user or your app disables/enables notifications, make that reflect in the SharedPreferences.

Also, you could make a utility class to post notifications so that you don't have to add a check in a lot of different places.

```
public class NotificationUtil {

    public static void showNotification(
            Context context,
            int notificationId,
            int iconId,
            Class parentStackClass,
            String notificationTitle,
            String notificationText
    ) {
        boolean showNotification = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(context)
                .getBoolean("SHOW_NOTIFICATION", true);

        if (!showNotification) return;

        android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                        .setSmallIcon(iconId)
                        .setContentTitle(notificationTitle)
                        .setContentText(notificationText);

        Intent resultIntent = new Intent(context, parentStackClass);


        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);
        stackBuilder.addParentStack(parentStackClass);
        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
                stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(
                        0,
                        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
                );
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);

        NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        mNotificationManager.notify(notificationId, mBuilder.build());
    }

}
```

Comment: please see my attached screenshot. There how can I enable/disable the Show Notifications programatically.

Answer (score 1):

We can't programatically turn on/ turn off notification. We can check the status of notification with below snippet

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
     AppOpsManager mAppOps = (AppOpsManager) context.getSystemService(Context.APP_OPS_SERVICE);
     ApplicationInfo appInfo = context.getApplicationInfo();
     String pkg = context.getApplicationContext().getPackageName();
     int uid = appInfo.uid;
     Class appOpsClass;
     try {
       appOpsClass = Class.forName(AppOpsManager.class.getName());
       Method checkOpNoThrowMethod =
           appOpsClass.getMethod(CHECK_OP_NO_THROW, Integer.TYPE, Integer.TYPE, String.class);

       Field opPostNotificationValue = appOpsClass.getDeclaredField(OP_POST_NOTIFICATION);
       int value = (int) opPostNotificationValue.get(Integer.class);
       return ((int) checkOpNoThrowMethod.invoke(mAppOps, value, uid,
           pkg) == AppOpsManager.MODE_ALLOWED);
     } catch (ClassNotFoundException | NoSuchMethodException | NoSuchFieldException
         | InvocationTargetException | IllegalAccessException ex) {
       Utils.logExceptionCrashLytics(ex);
     }
     // checked
   } else {
     // unchecked
   }
```

Answer (score -4):

You can save it in SharedPreferences and every time you want to display a notification you can check it.