# Android. Show notification checkbox

Tags: android

I see in `JellyBean` added checkbox `"Show notification"` in application info.
Is it possible check in my application enabled notifications or no?
I think it is impossible to enable notifications programatically or may be exist any way?

Comment: Already asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11649654/1898809
Looks like the answer is no i'm afriad

Answer (score 0):

Your guess is right its possible to disable notifications from other apps. you can only control notifications generated by your own app.Perhaps on rooted devices you could do some magic, but that shall not really count for wider audience.

Check out

[Turn off notifications of an app programatically on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15819249/turn-off-notifications-of-an-app-programatically-on-android)

[Android: is it possible to remove a system-managed notification programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16019868/android-is-it-possible-to-remove-a-system-managed-notification-programmatically)