# How to enable or disable the Notification LED in Android?

Tags: android, notifications, android-notifications, led

How is it possible to enable or disable the Notification LED in Android?
I want to set it default that the LED isn't shown anymore until I enable it again. So the LED is completely turned off.

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot do that from your code. Perhaps on rooted devices you could do some magic, but that shall not really count for wider audience. You can only control notifications generated by your own app.

Comment: how can i set this as default? Always if I get a message, the LED is again the other color and has the old intervall.

Comment: In this case you must change the configuration in your phone. But programmatically like my answer

Comment: and how can i change this programmatically ? Isn't there a easy way?

Comment: is there not a notificationlistener? then i could always modify the led after tat

Comment: for example if your sms app throw a led notification, you can't stop it from your app, you can only manage the led notification of your app, see this posts http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17667406/programmatically-disabling-enabling-notifications http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15819249/turn-off-notifications-of-an-app-programatically-on-android http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16019868/android-is-it-possible-to-remove-a-system-managed-notification-programmatically